# Pagination links on CP Module screen are not clickable

Tags: control-panel, add-on-development, module, pagination, table

I'm working on a module that's outputting data using `$this->EE->load->library('table')`.

I'm passing this back to my `index()` function to render things:

```
return array(
    'rows' => $rows,
    'pagination' => array(
        'page_query_string' => TRUE,
        'base_url'    => $this->_full_url(), // My own function
        'per_page'   => 20,
        'total_rows' => $total_rows
    )
);
```

This is all working wonderfully. In fact, my pagination links are working wonderfully as well. They're generating URLs like this:

```
http://addons.clearbold.localhost:8888/system/index.php?S=a87b760ae58c317d28e7d1ebf3c8f374e89173a5&D=cp&C=addons_modules&M=show_module_cp&module=module_name&tbl_offset=20
```

And if I do a View Source and click the links enabled in the source view, they take me to exactly the page I want to see.

On the CP screen, though... I can hover over the links and see the right URLs in the status bar. My cursor switches to the hover state to show they're clickable. But when I click them – Nothing happens. The browser doesn't follow the link.

Why aren't they clickable? I've tried recent Chrome, Safari & Firefox versions.

Full pagination output:

```
</table><p class="tbl_513a025265a0f" id="paginationLinks">&nbsp;<a href="http://addons.clearbold.localhost:8888/system/index.php?S=b8223938e000fecfb1e3065326d799591cd9bda9&D=cp&C=addons_modules&M=show_module_cp&module=module_name&amp;tbl_offset="><img src="http://addons.clearbold.localhost:8888/themes/cp_themes/default/images/pagination_prev_button.gif" width="13" height="13" alt="&lt;" /></a>&nbsp;<a href="http://addons.clearbold.localhost:8888/system/index.php?S=b8223938e000fecfb1e3065326d799591cd9bda9&D=cp&C=addons_modules&M=show_module_cp&module=module_name&amp;tbl_offset=">1</a>&nbsp;<strong>2</strong>&nbsp;<a href="http://addons.clearbold.localhost:8888/system/index.php?S=b8223938e000fecfb1e3065326d799591cd9bda9&D=cp&C=addons_modules&M=show_module_cp&module=module_name&amp;tbl_offset=40">3</a>&nbsp;<a href="http://addons.clearbold.localhost:8888/system/index.php?S=b8223938e000fecfb1e3065326d799591cd9bda9&D=cp&C=addons_modules&M=show_module_cp&module=module_name&amp;tbl_offset=40"><img src="http://addons.clearbold.localhost:8888/themes/cp_themes/default/images/pagination_next_button.gif" width="13" height="13" alt="&gt;" /></a>&nbsp;</p>
```

Comment: What does the HTML look like when you inspect the code? Any obvious issues?

Comment: No, no issues at all. The links are clickable when you view source, and you can hover over them and see that they're links. Everything about them is a link. The browser just doesn't follow them when clicked. Updated question with full markup.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to one of my teammates for suggesting I disable CSS & JS to troubleshoot.

The table is AJAXified, which overrides the link values. I was missing this:

```
$this->EE->table->set_base_url('C=addons_modules'.AMP.'M=show_module_cp'.AMP.'module=module_name');
```

Which the AJAX links require to refresh the table.