# Pagination links on CP module's view are not clickable

Tags: control-panel, add-on-development, module, pagination, table

I have a problem quite similar to the one found 
[here](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/7155/pagination-links-on-cp-module-screen-are-not-clickable), where I am trying to form a table using the tutorial found on [Ellis Lab's site](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/table.html). I found some of their guide totally lacking on pagination, and as a result when I implement it, I lose my table sorting and have links for pagination that do not work when clicked.

After looking on StackExchange I found the helpful post above, so that now I am at the same starting state as the OP's problem. My code looks like this:

```
$method_url = BASE.AMP.'C=addons_modules'.AMP.'M=show_module_cp'.AMP.'module=my_module'.AMP.'method=my_method';    
return array(
        'rows' => array_slice($rows, $offset, 5),
        'pagination' => array(
        'page_query_string'     => TRUE,
        'base_url'      => $method_url,
        'per_page'          => 5,
        'total_rows'        => count($rows)
        )
    );
```

However, adding $this->EE->table->set_base_url() does not solve it for me. Although I may need to add it in a place that I did not try - the solution post did not specify.

Perhaps the best way I could summarize would be this: 
What is the EllisLab tutorial missing from making a functional pagination/sorting table?

Answer (score 1):

I used `set_base_url()` in my `index()` function, where I set up the table.

```
$this->EE->load->library('table');
$this->EE->table->set_columns(array(
// columns
));
$this->EE->table->set_base_url('C=addons_modules&M=show_module_cp&module=my_module');
$data = $this->EE->table->datasource('_datasource');
$data['base_url'] = $this->base_url; // Available in my View
return $this->EE->load->view('mcp_my_module', $data, TRUE);
```

And in my `_datasource` function, which needs to give the pagination array a `base_url`:

```
$base_url = $this->_full_url();

function _full_url()
{
    $s = empty($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) ? '' : ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "s" : "";
    $sp = strtolower($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]);
    $protocol = substr($sp, 0, strpos($sp, "/")) . $s;
    $port = ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] == "80") ? "" : (":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]);

    $non_offset_uri = explode('&tbl_offset=',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $non_offset = $non_offset_uri[0];

    return $protocol . "://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $port . $non_offset;
}
```

Yes, I wrote my own function to set the base_url for pagination.

Also - I have this as the return for my `_datasource` function:

```
return array(
    'rows' => $rows,
    'pagination' => array(
        'page_query_string' => TRUE,
        'base_url'    => $base_url,
        'per_page'   => $per_page,
        'total_rows' => $total_rows
    )
);
```

I start it with this:

```
function _datasource($state)
{
    //var_dump($state['offset']);
    $offset = 0;
    if ($state['offset'] != 0)
        $offset = (int)$state['offset'];
    $per_page = 20;
    $base_url = $this->_full_url();
```

And use those values in my query:

```
LIMIT ?,?",array($offset,$per_page));
```

To get the current page records.

Note that I have **TWO** queries in my `_datasource` function: One returns all rows to get the `$total_rows` value. The other uses `LIMIT` to get the current page's records.

```
$count_results = $this->EE->db->query("SELECT * FROM exp_audit_log ORDER BY timestamp desc");
$total_rows = $count_results->num_rows();
```

Comment: I added limit via active record, and the page does not render pagination when it is included. 
The query is like this: 
$this->EE->db->select('field1, field2')        ->from('table')       ->limit('5', $offset)         ->get()         ->result_array();

Comment: Are you using a View? Or just an `index()` function? What if your `index()` function just returns `$data['table_html'] . $data['pagination_html'];`?

Comment: Did you set `$offset = $state['offset']`? Are you sure you have more than 5 rows?

Comment: I am using a view, not `index()` and `$offset = $state['offset']`. The query has 20 rows.

Comment: And your view has these? `<?= $table_html ?>
<?= $pagination_html ?>`

Comment: Generally. Following the tutorial, I formatted it `<?php
    $this->table->set_columns($headers);
    $data = $this->table->datasource('overview_datasource', $defaults);

    echo $data['table_html'];
    echo $data['pagination_html'];
?>`

Comment: Before the return, can you wrap the array in `var_dump`? So you'd have `var_dump(array(
    'rows' => array_slice($rows, $offset, 5),
    'pagination' => array(
    'page_query_string'     => TRUE,
    'base_url'      => $method_url,
    'per_page'          => 5,
    'total_rows'        => count($rows)
    )); exit;`

Comment: I hope this isn't too hideous... 
`array (size=2)
  'rows' => 
    // yadda yadda
  'pagination' => 
    array (size=4)
      'page_query_string' => boolean true
      'base_url' => string 'admin.php?S=651fb2c5a1367f6f90facd151f0e70a74d7d769d&amp;D=cp&amp;C=addons_modules&amp;M=show_module_cp&amp;module=eequiz&amp;method=overview' (length=141)
      'per_page' => int 5
      'total_rows' => int 5`

Comment: It says `per_page` and `total_rows` are equal. Hence, no pagination :) Total rows must be greater than per page for there to be more than a page=1.

Comment: One thing to note: I have TWO queries in my `_datasource`. One gets ALL rows to get the count, the other uses `LIMIT` to get the current page. Your `total_rows` are based on `LIMIT`.

Comment: Basically because the tutorial version of the pagination array is doing the same work as the Active Record query we are getting no pagination, which comes as no surprise. Removing the limit from my query gives me: ...`'pagination' => 
    array (size=4)
      'page_query_string' => boolean true
      'base_url' => string 'admin.php?S=651fb2c5a1367f6f90facd151f0e70a74d7d769d&amp;D=cp&amp;C=addons_modules&amp;M=show_module_cp&amp;module=eequiz&amp;method=overview' (length=141)
      'per_page' => int 5
      'total_rows' => int 25`

Comment: This returns us to pagination buttons with that are unclickable and no sorting to the table... Does this mean that I should be building the return array() differently than the tutorial says?

Comment: And that's fine. You just need to do an additional query to give a value to `$total_rows`. See updated answer.

Comment: I have to say, I didn't figure out sorting, and didn't need it. Unclickable buttons were purely the result of the Base URL not being set correctly. Using Chrome Dev Tools and the Network tab, you can see the URL that's called when you click a pagination link. Copy that URL and paste it into your browser. If you just get the CP homepage, you'll see the problem. It has to call THIS page.

Comment: And, the pagination array needs its own base_url.

Comment: Updated again with how I set the base_url for pagination.

Comment: I saw that in your post and found that I had success with the URL thanks to you :) . Reading your updated answer, my `'rows' => array_slice($rows, $offset, $limit),` does the job of one of your queries, and `'total_rows' => count($rows)` does the job of the other...

Comment: Seems like we are on the same page here. My URL is simply: `$method_url = BASE.AMP.'C=addons_modules'.AMP.'M=show_module_cp'.AMP.'module=my_module'.AMP.'method=my_method'`. 
Is this style missing something? Edited to OP as well

Comment: Is this what you see in Chrome after clicking a pagination link? http://circa1977.net/snap/pagination-url.png

Comment: Yes, exactly. However, when I can open up the next page  (clicking the buttons or the numbers) as a new tab, and those URIs have the "&method=..." segment, which the dev tool does not show in the Network tab. I'm not sure if that is related, or it is just food-for-thought?

Comment: If the method you're calling is not `index()`, the method is needed. Your base URL might not have that, which means you need to override or update the base URL.

Comment: Would I make a change to `'base_url' => $method_url` in addition to updating the base URL?

Comment: By default, it was adding `&tbl_offset` onto the URL with `&tbl_offset` already on it. That's why I wrote my `full_url()` function.

Comment: `'base_url' => $method_url` is the one that matters. The `$base_url` value I feed that is the variable within the `_datasource` function, not the value for the module/`index()` function.

Comment: I see. Since I am not in the `index()`, I do not need to update `$this->EE->table->set_base_url()` at all. Even with it commented out that command commented out I experience no change in behavior.

Comment: Gotta look at the live URL that jQuery's trying to load. Have you actually captured that and pasted it in a new window? Something's not matching up.

Comment: Yes, the question then is which jQuery function is capturing the click? Left-click only, moreover, since middle-click opens in a new tab without a problem in Chrome...

Comment: Not sure what to tell you there. I just made the link it was following work.